# Do apache rewrite engine handles PHP require_once file path?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Normally, each file requests from Url reaches Webserver. Assume 'Apache' as webserver here.

**`https://mypersonaldomain.com/browse.html`** :It will hit apache server and from the server, 'browse.html' is returned.

If the rewrite engine is on, then it will be passed via Rewrite query and forms new Url(if any match in rewrite conditions), and returns file from obtained path

Assume, browse.html.php

```
<?php
require_once('somefile.php');
?>
<html>
    <head>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="otherJSfile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, How the `somefile.php` is obtained

1. will reach Apache server? will it flows through rewrite scripts?

(or)

2. will it directly get the file?

I am clear, the script files loaded in HTML Head section, are hitting Apache server.I am not sure whether the files loaded via PHP `require_once` are hitting Apache server or not.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

`require_once('somefile.php')` will fetch `somefile.php` directly from the file system - apache is not involved in loading it. The [include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) configuration variable will be used to find where to load it from.

You can answer this question for yourself simply by looking at your apache log file - you will see no requests for the included file.

It is *possible* to use `http` URLs in `require` statements (as long as PHP is built with the relevant [fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php)), but if you do that, the remote server may return the *result* of the script rather than the actual code (which may, or may not, be what you're trying to achieve)

Comment: Thank you Paul, I checked in apache access log, the file included via **require_once** is not listed there. however, I am still facing the problem in including files via **require_once**. Will look into my code and get back. 
please let me know, if any custom method is applicable to extend **require_once** method to rewrite the file path?

Comment: Ah I see - you want include files on paths that get processed by mod_rewrite? There's no good reason to need that. Just include files as normal.